# What input does tf.contrib.seq2seq.TraininHelper expect in a Bahdanau seq2seq implementation?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Having read the [Bahdanau paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473) and translated it into the current tf.contrib.seq2seq API, I'm confused on what I'm supposed to feed into my decoder. In particular, TrainingHelper looks like it should receive a time-shifted list of labels.

The below is my working example, but I'm not sure it's correct.

```py
# Given: 
#    annotations: encoder outputs, reshaped to 
#    (batch_size, time, encoder_size)
#    labels: ground truth, shaped (batch_size, FORECAST_HORIZON)
if params.get('ATTENTION') == 'Bahdanau':
    bahdanau = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(
        num_units=ATTENTION_SIZE,
        memory=annotations,
        normalize=False,
        name='BahdanauAttention')
    attn_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
        cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(DECODER_SIZE, forget_bias=1.0),
        attention_mechanism=bahdanau,
        output_attention=False,
        name="attention_wrapper")
    helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(
        inputs=annotations,  # ??????
        sequence_length=[WINDOW_LENGTH]*BATCH_SIZE,
        name="TrainingDecoderHelper")
```

Note the third-to-last line.

Is TrainingHelper supposed to be feeding the encoder annotations into the attention-wrapped decoder system?

- pro: if `inputs` is not shaped like `annotations`, the AttentionWrapper ends up complaining about shapes - the only place such a shape arises from in the system is in the encoder.
- con: where does the decoder get the ground truth if this is correct?
- con: the attention-wrapped decoder (`attn_cell`) already knows where to get annotations (isn't that the point of the attention mechanism?)

Anyway, practically speaking, I'm getting a system that is trainable, but something seems fishy to me (including the fact that it's underperforming relative to a simple LSTM, but that's definitely tangential at present).